# IE creates a pop up on a JSF page. Background of popup needs to disabled

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, jsf

CSS creates a pop up on a JSF page. Requirement is background of the popup should be  disabled. My source is working fine as long as I am working in any browsers except IE.

CSS :

```
<style type="text/css">
    #overlay {
        visibility: hidden;
        display:none;
        position:fixed;
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background-color: rgba(252, 252, 252, 0.9);
        background-image:none;
        opacity:0.5;
        z-index:99999;
        overflow:auto;
    }

    #popup {
        display:none;
        position:fixed;
        left:30%;
        top:30%;
        width:650px;
        height:200px;
        margin-top:-75px;
        margin-left:-150px;
        padding: 20px;
        background:#FFFFFF;
        background-image:none;
        border:2px solid #000;
        border-radius: 5px;
        z-index:100000;
    }

    #popup .content {
        max-height: 90%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Please help me or direct me. Thanks

Comment: Mention the browser's version which is many a times very important. What JSF component generates this CSS? Otherwise, it belongs to HTML/CSS tags only.

Comment: Could you post a JSFIDDLE link to a sample code?